# Calling UI game over not functioning correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I Have a Enemy Guard Script for a stealth game where ckecked if player was spotted to show the game over condition. (game over text at UI).

```
void Start()
{     
    if(player == null)
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }
    viewAngle = spotlight.spotAngle;
    originalSpotlighyColour = spotlight.color;

    Vector3[] waypoints = new Vector3[pathHolder.childCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
    {
        waypoints [i] = pathHolder.GetChild (i).position;
        waypoints [i] = new Vector3 (waypoints [i].x, transform.position.y, waypoints [i].z);
    }

    StartCoroutine (FollowPath (waypoints));

}

void Update()
{
    if (CanSeePlayer())
    {
        playerVisibleTimer += Time.deltaTime;
       // spotlight.color = Color.red;
    } else
    {
        playerVisibleTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
       // spotlight.color = originalSpotlighyColour;
    }
    playerVisibleTimer = Mathf.Clamp(playerVisibleTimer, 0, timeToSpotPlayer);
    spotlight.color = Color.Lerp(originalSpotlighyColour, Color.red, playerVisibleTimer / timeToSpotPlayer);

    if(playerVisibleTimer>= timeToSpotPlayer)
    {
        if (OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer != null)
        {
            OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer();
            StopAllCoroutines();
            Seek();
            GameUI.gameIsOver = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The condition is simple:

If the player is seen, the game over image appears, and player gonna press the SPACE key to restart the stage. But the the image at UI show just one time, game over function is not called again. Are just called at the first time when player lose the level, after this you can go inside the enemy vision and nothing gonna happens.

Comment: Your on-spotted cancels all coroutines, but you start a coroutine in Start. You don't call Start manually.

Comment: @Draco18s I do not know if I understood correctly. What do I have to change?

Comment: You need to reset things. You aren't currently.

Comment: `after this you can go inside the enemy vision ` .. so how I understand it you want kind of a "deathcam", a replay of the last seconds, to review how you lost? In this case I'ld say the code you provided is not enough to understand what happens there.